# Android - periodically wake up from standby mode?

Tags: android

I have an app that needs to send a periodic heart beat to a server, but when the phone goes into standby mode the background heartbeat thread dies. Is there anyway to wake the phone from standby, send the heartbeat and then go back to sleep programmatically? I want to avoid using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to send a heart beat while the phone is asleep?  That sounds like a horrible battery drain.

Comment: It sounds like you need to set up a service instead of using a thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway to wake the phone from standby, send the heartbeat and then go back to sleep
>   programmatically?

Use `AlarmManager` with a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/) illustrating its use (along with a `WakefulIntentService` you will want, to make sure the device does not fall back asleep during your network I/O).

> I want to avoid using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK if possible.

You cannot do network I/O without a `WakeLock`, because the device will fall back asleep during the I/O. Using `AlarmManager`, you can arrange to only hold a `WakeLock` during the actual heartbeat work, not 100% of the time.